# MVC ActionFilterAttribute but only on main View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute

I have an attribute on my Controller

```
[ABC]  
MyController
```

The Attribute checks something but I only want to check once per page.

```
public class ABCAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        ////Do some check
    }
```

The **OnActionExecuting** fires for every element on the page. Partials etc.

How do I check to see if the **filterContext** is the **main page** and not a child resource on the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class VerificationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public VerificationAttribute ()
    {
     }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //We don't care about children/partials
        if (filterContext.IsChildAction)
            return;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignore, think I miss read your question